# Returning an object through function call prints undefined

Tags: javascript, object

Im requesting some data in a JSON file that is returning an object.
My issue is that I only get `undefined` from the return function.

My JS:

```
requestData = function (targetId) {
    var targetObject;

    var jsonUrl = "data.json";
    $.getJSON( jsonUrl, {
        format: "json"
    })

    .done(function( data ) {
        var idx = -1;

        for (var i = 0, len = data.element.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (data.element[i].year === targetId) {
                idx = i;
                targetObject= data.element[i];
                //console.log(targetObject); -- prints the object fine
                break;
            }
        }

        return targetObject;
    })
}

console.log(requestData("id")); //returns "undefined"
```

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: That is to be expected as getJSON is async. Which is to say it is a non-blocking function.

Comment: `requestData` has no `return` call, so returns `undefined`.  The `return` in the `done()` call is asynchronously triggered, after your `console.log()` call has completed.